# How to push new FieldArray from outside render function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have this code to push new `FieldArray` every time I click the button, but it is only applicable inside `renderContract FieldArray` component.

```
const renderContact = ({ fields, meta: { error } }) => (
    <div>
    {fields.map((contact, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <div className="row form-pad">
          <div className="col-md-3">
            <span>Country Code {index + 1}:<span className="requiredField text-danger"> * </span>: </span>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-7">
            <Field name={`${contact}.landlineCountryCode`}  component={renderField}type="text"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
    <button className="btn btn-primary"  onClick={() => fields.push({})}>
      Add Contact
    </button>
  </div>
)
```

and render it like this on parent form component:

```
<FieldArray name="contact" component={renderContact} />
```

How can I use `fields.push({})` outside fieldArray?

**EDIT:**

I tried this but to no avail:

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => props.dispatch(arrayPush('PersonalInfoForm', 'contact', [{}]))}> Add Contact</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dispatch an action `arrayPush` with the `form` and the `fieldname` to effect a `fields.push({})` from outside the FieldArray

```
import { arrayPush } from 'redux-form';

// ...
dispatch(arrayPush('myForm', 'contact', {}));
```

Comment: I tried this already `<button type="button" onClick={() => props.dispatch(arrayPush('PersonalInfoForm', 'contact', [{}]))}> Add Contact</button>` but did not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: arrayPush('PersonalInfoForm', 'contact', {})

Comment: I already figured out what my bug is. so your right all along. I name my form differently than the name of my component.
`let personalInfoForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'syncValidation',
  validate
})(PersonalInfoForm)`